# How To Remove Lines Not Containing A Word

Tags: regex

I have a large text file with lines and I just want to keep the lines that have the word `"cat"` in it. Is there anyway to achieve this with regex? I'm using VS code for the editing. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify it further, I'm trying to remove the lines that doesn't contain the word "cat" like below.

my text document looks like this (example)

```
cat 1
dog 2
cat 3
dog 4
fish 1
```

Comment: RegEx allows you to describe patterns. The rest is done by a programming language.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm trying to figure out the pattern to replace it using vscode.